# Map attribution for QGIS kids maps

Tags: attribution

I am making a map for a kids magazine in QGIS. I am using mostly free data sources (Natural Earth) and then in Illustrator, I am adding locations (famous landmarks) by hand. My question is- do I have to add any attribution for where I got the data? Are there any cartographers who publish in kids books (not scholarly or text book) and where do I site the map info- if anywhere. Can it be in a "credits" area in the back of the book?

Comment: It really depends on the data you are using. For example, see the [OSM](https://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/Licence/Attribution_Guidelines) attribution requirements

Comment: credit the image/data and add an appendix at the end of the book.

Answer (score 10):

You should follow the terms of use or attribution requirements of the data you are using. There may be no specific terms of use stated, but there may be a license (e.g [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/about/cclicenses/)) which will set the terms of use.

For Natural Earth data, which is in the public domain, the [terms of use](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/about/terms-of-use/) state:

> No permission is needed to use Natural Earth. Crediting the authors is
> unnecessary. However, if you wish to cite the map data, simply use one of the following.
>
> - Short text: Made with Natural Earth.
> - Long text: Made with Natural Earth. Free vector and raster map data @
>   naturalearthdata.com.

For Open Street Map data, which is available under available under the Open Database License, see the [Licence/Attribution Guidelines](https://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/Licence/Attribution_Guidelines#Attribution_text).

As to where/how you attribute in your kids magazine, that really depends on the style guidelines of the magazine.  You should ask them.  If they don't have any, I would just use a short sentence attributing your sources (according to their requirements) in small text in the caption. E.g.

> *Made with OpenStreetMap (openstreetmap.org/copyright) and Natural Earth data*